# How to add a condition to control entry or not after a condition matched

Tags: pine-script

Is it available that add a judgement condition after a condition matched?

For example:
In Day timeframe, I want to set the `stratgey.entry` if `Close > Open` and judge that if next day's `open > close[1]`.

In code, it seems like..

```
LongCondition = close > open

As is:
If LongCondition
 strategy.entry('long',...)

To be:
If LongCondition
 If Open > close[1]
```

This is not work, how to achieve that condition after condition match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the historical data of your first condition with the [History reference operator []](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).

So, if your first condition is:

```
first_condition = close > open
```

And if your second (judgement condition) is:

```
second_condition = open > close[1]
```

Then you would do:

```
buy_condition = first_condition[1] and second_condition

if (buy_condition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

`first_condition[1]` would tell you if your first condition was `true` on the previous bar. And then you can `and` your judgement condition with that and enter the trade.

Comment: It works perfectly!
But I forgot one of the most important things
' When the second condition is also met, entry immeditely, not entry on next bar '
The current method is that if conditions all match, will enter on next bar.
Is there a way to enter the market at the current BAR based on this logic?

Comment: Set `process_orders_on_close` to `true` in your `strategy()` call. It will enter on bar close.